# Hibernate get one column from a one to many connection

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create a java class that contains only 1 column from OneToMany ManyToOne etc. type connection not the whole row.

How can I do that?

(I'm not sure that I could express myself so I made an example)

```
TABLE e_skill
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    skill_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

TABLE t_person
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    primary_skill int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (primary_skill) REFERENCES e_skill(id)
);

TABLE t_secondaryskills
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    t_person_id int NOT NULL,
    skill_name int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (t_person_id) REFERENCES t_person(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (skill_name) REFERENCES e_skill(id)
);

public enum Skill {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_person")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    //????????
    //get skill_name column from e_skill
    //????????
    private Skill primarySkill;

    @OneToMany
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    //????????
    //get skill_name column from e_skill
    //????????
    private Set<Skill> secondarySkills;

    //getters setters
}
```

The only way I could do it now is to create a Entity to represent the e_skill table, I want to avoid that, because I only need 1 column from it.

Comment: A word of advice: if you push the ORM paradigm too far, you'll get poor performance. What you need here is an explicit query, not ORM magic.

Comment: And is this too far ? :( I only want limit the joined columns

Comment: You want a SELECT clause without mapping it as an entity. That's pushing it, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can't do what you want because of the secondary skills (because it's a collection). You can only map the primary skill name though using the [`@SecondaryTable` annotation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/SecondaryTable).

When you map things using an ORM there's no such thing as **I only want a column in this scenario** as you're mapping Objects, and usually in your objects you don't want to replicate data (unless they are outside your domain model). If this is unacceptable for you, I suggest you to take a look at other tools like myBtais, which gives you full control on the data you get back.

So bottom line, map your skill as an entity and live with it even if it has many columns, or choose a different tool (but not an ORM).